# Prevent task (anti-malware program) from being ended

Tags: python, antivirus, taskmanager

I am currently developing a anti-virus/anti-malware program for Windows 10. I need the program to be protected; so that it may not be ended via the task manager. For example, If I were to try to end the `Antimalware Service Executable` with the task manager, I'd receive the following message:

```
Unable to terminate process
The operation could not be completed.
Access is denied.
```

Is there any way I could add this feature programmatically; maybe via Python?

EDIT: This is for an aggressive antivirus/antimalware that minimizes false-positives and slip-throughs. Yes I'm aware commercial options exist, but I am not looking for one.

Comment: Why would your program want to go against the user wishes?

Comment: This kind of sounds like malware itself...?

Comment: @imreal It's more protection from software that has administrative power impersonating the user trying to end the process that I am concerned about.

Comment: If the virus has root it's over anyway. The user needs to be able to terminate programs at her discretion.

Comment: @redFIVE Nope, It's for an anti-virus/malware program I am developing. Commercial software, such as Norton, have this feature.

Comment: @imreal Not exactly, I'm trying to prevent that; I am trying to make it extremely aggressive against elevated actions.

Comment: I can close Norton whenever I want.

Comment: The thing is that if the virus has root, preventing your program from being killed is not going to help, the virus could delete it, modify it, install a rootkit, etc ...

Comment: @redFIVE In my experience, I've seen this exact dialog when attempting to do so on a computer of mine around a year or two ago.

Comment: You probably want a windows policy then maybe? What you are describing is literal malware.

If the administrator can't stop it? Who can? As people have already stated, if a virus has root/administration level access its all over anyway.

Your entire scenario is based of unsound reasoning.

Comment: Software like Norton Antivirus usually has the user application that you can close at will and a service (or rather multiple services) running in the background that requires you to use management tools (like service manager) to stop. That said, the information about Windows services is common knowledge and can be easily found if you know what you are looking for. And if you do not know what you are looking for, maybe you should not be writing anti-virus software.

Comment: And writing an anti-virus in python is a questionable choice in the first place

Comment: @MadWombat I am sure of my choices; but I have located what I needed, and have posted the answer. (Although I have to wait to accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After conduction further research, I have located an article that perfectly describes what I am looking for. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Services/protecting-anti-malware-services-
This will help me create the program, and protect it adequately.